# how to call a JSView from an XSJS file?

Tags: sapui5, hana, hana-studio

I know I can call other JS files from XSJS by making a `.xsjslib` file. I would like to be able to call a JSView instead. Is this possible?

**Note:** the reason for me to this is that I can then use the SAPUI5 libraries and make it easier to import external libraries to my code. This is more of general question than trying to target a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

that's not possible, as the UI5 JSView is in the front end and XSJS is server-side code.  Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to call external libraries within xsjs or xsjslib, such as js-xlsx or pdfmake?

Comment: You can do that in node.js in XS Advanced: https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/xsa-node-modules.html . You can also call node.js from outside and connect to HANA using the HDB module https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hxe-nodejs-setup.html